# Google Admin Directory API is returning 400 bad request

Tags: java, client, google-directory-api

I'm experimenting with the Java client for Google Admin SDK, specifically the Directory API. It's based on the use of GoogleCredentials just like Google Drive API. However, unlike Google Drive I'm getting 400 - bad request errors with Directory. I setup the API as follows:

```
Directory directory = new Directory.Builder(TRANSPORT, FACTORY, credential).build();
Directory.Users.List list = directory.users().list();
Users users = list.execute();
```

The last execute() produces the error and stack trace listed at the bottom of the post. I'm using the following scopes to authorize myself. I also use the Drive API as you can see.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
```

Accessing the Drive API works like a charm. I can request files without problems. If I perform a simple operation on the Directory API, however, I get the error and stack trace listed below. I should mention that both the Drive API and Directory API refer to the same Google Apps domain for which I'm an administrator. I also enabled both APIs in the Google API console. For the rest, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and I'm wondering if anyone else has seen something similar or otherwise has experience with the accessing this API through the Java client.

Thanks,

Ralph

```
[ERROR] com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 OK
[ERROR] {
[ERROR]   "code" : 400,
[ERROR]   "errors" : [ {
[ERROR]     "domain" : "global",
[ERROR]     "message" : "Bad Request",
[ERROR]     "reason" : "badRequest"
[ERROR]   } ],
[ERROR]   "message" : "Bad Request"
[ERROR] }
[ERROR]     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
[ERROR]     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:111)
[ERROR]     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:38)
[ERROR]     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
[ERROR]     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1042)
[ERROR]     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
[ERROR]     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
[ERROR]     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
[ERROR]     at com.arcus.example.server.api.DirectoryAPI.getEmails(DirectoryAPI.java:29)
[ERROR]     at com.arcus.example.server.action.CreateExampleDelegate.execute(CreateExampleDelegate.java:29)
[ERROR]     at com.arcus.example.server.action.CreateExampleActionHandler.execute(CreateExampleActionHandler.java:28)
[ERROR]     at com.arcus.example.server.action.CreateExampleActionHandler.execute(CreateExampleActionHandler.java:13)
[ERROR]     at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.AbstractDispatchImpl.doExecute(AbstractDispatchImpl.java:156)
[ERROR]     at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.AbstractDispatchImpl.execute(AbstractDispatchImpl.java:112)
[ERROR]     at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.AbstractDispatchServiceImpl.execute(AbstractDispatchServiceImpl.java:84)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
[ERROR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
[ERROR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
[ERROR]     at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
[ERROR]     at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
[ERROR]     at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
[ERROR]     at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
[ERROR]     at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.AbstractHttpSessionSecurityCookieFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpSessionSecurityCookieFilter.java:69)
[ERROR]     at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
[ERROR]     at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
[ERROR]     at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
[ERROR]     at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[ERROR]     at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[ERROR]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[ERROR]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[ERROR]     at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[ERROR]     at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[ERROR]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[ERROR]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:369)
[ERROR]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectServerRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:352)
[ERROR]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:115)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
[ERROR]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
[ERROR]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:438)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you don't specify the user to use or the domain to use,

you need to add this information here:

```
Directory directory = new Directory.Builder(TRANSPORT, FACTORY, credential).build();
Directory.Users.List list = directory.users().list();
list.setCustomer("name.surname@yourdomain.com");
Users users = list.execute();
```

Now if you have permission problem the return code of the error will be 403 = authorization issue.

Comment: Hi Sabrina, thanks for your reply! I missed it because for some reason I didn't enable email notifications... I have it working now!

Answer (score 8):

The solution is:

```
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    GoogleCredential credential;

    Collection<String> SCOPES = new ArrayList<String>();
    SCOPES.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user");



    credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
             .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
             .setServiceAccountUser("adminEmail@yourDomain.com")
             .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
             .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
             new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
            .build();

    Directory directory = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();

    Directory.Users.List list = directory.users().list();
    list.setDomain("yourDomain.com");
    Users users = list.execute();
```

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = File location of the key (API Console)
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = Service Account from API COnsole

Add the scope from the control panel of your domain, using the method Service Account
https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

And activate Admin SDK in your API Console.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Maven, just add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-admin</artifactId>
    <version>directory_v1-rev4-1.15.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
```